# I need to create a node js script that will read a text file and ouput a graph. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, fs

There will be 144 Inputs these inputs are times that it was recorded on. I wish to graph this data each 'tower' gets taller the more times it is seen. The possible Inputs are 24 hour time with only the 10's digit so 10:34 will become 10:3. So I need a script that will count repeats of these inputs and a script that will graph it.

What npm should I use to create the graphs from the info? How do I count repeats from the input file?

Sample Input file:

```
, 7:3, 7:4, 7:5, 8:0
```

**Note samples are not connected**

Sample Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to answer questions so broadly, it's intended to help you with concrete code problems.

Comment: What I want to know is how I can output this info to a graph in the form of an PNG or a SVG. I htink plotly would work but I do not know how to count the repeats this is not a broad question.